# Redshift/F.lux not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, colors, redshift, f.lux

I have installed both Redshift and f.lux on my Ubuntu 16.04 machine to try to change the color temperature of my screen. I can open the apps, but neither of them has an effect on the screen color tone. On F.lux, when I try to preview the color temperature, nothing happens. Does anybody know what could be going on here? Why isn't this working?

Note, I am using an NVIDIA GeForce GTX 980 Ti GPU.

Comment: Could you update your question with a screenshot of the Redshift panel applet open?

Comment: See my answer. I fixed it by switching to the correct driver.

Comment: Good! You should self-accept it. :)

Comment: One solution that I found the easiest to implement (after searching for drivers and whatnot) was the one [here](https://github.com/jonls/redshift/issues/572), not related to RedShift or f.lux: switching to the built-in [GNOME night-light](https://www.gnome.org/news/2017/03/gnome-3-24-released/attachment/night-light/) in Ubuntu 17.10. Works very well with an Intel card and standard video driver. Just search for night light in Settings, can also be set for sunset/sunrise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I figured out how to use Redshift with my system. Basically, I was using the wrong display driver. When I went to the Additional Drivers tab in the Software & Updates app, I noticed I was using default Nouveau driver instead of the latest NVIDIA driver, and had the other tab set to "Do not use the device".

[image: Initial Driver Settings]

when I switched it to the NVIDIA driver tab and HDMA Driver with DKMS Format (daily-dkms) tab, and restarted the machine, it finally worked.

[image: New Driver settings]

Comment: At least redshift should work with the noveau drivers. Very curious to know what exactly went wrong there.

Comment: I am experiencing this issue as well on Kubuntu 16.10 with a GeForce GTX 670 - using the NVIDIA binary driver - version 367.57 from nvidia-367 (Recommended Driver).   I haven't tracked it down yet.  Edit - Looks like it's a known bug in my case: https://forum.justgetflux.com/topic/2373/sorry-we-only-support-8-and-10-bit-displays-right-now/16

Answer (score 12):

In a console type

```
redshift -l list
```

then I typed

```
redshift -l geoclue2
```

then it just worked.  I can even close and reopen it now and it works fine.

Comment: I thought it was like a config but no, changed startup apps command to `redshift-gtk -l geoclue2` and it worked, now it's info had non zero data, thx! Btw, geoclue also connected to internet, and I wasnt for a whole day, not sure if necessary tho.

Comment: confirmed: if you are going to be offline, only this works `redshift-gtk -l manual -l -12.34:56.78` (use geoclue2 to get the correct latitude and longitute prior, and each can be negatives)

Answer (score 5):

I tried to get both f.lux and Redshift to work without any solution so I just opted to go another route. So I went to the Ubuntu Software Manager and installed Night Light slider as pictured below. It works and certainly isn't making me die from strained eyes and a headache from earlier in the evening due to no sleep.

1. Search for Night Light on Ubuntu Software:

   [image]
2. Once installed, it just appears in your top right drop down menu and can be toggled to user preference.

   [image]

Comment: This question is about Ubuntu 16.04. You should point out in your answer it applies to **Ubuntu 18.04+** only.

Comment: Thanks @radiostereio, really helped me out!

Answer (score 1):

Redshift is **time-based.** It will change the color of your screen provided the following two conditions are met:

- It can determine where you are (either via the default network-based location service or if you started it with the `-l` switch giving it coordinates)
- It is evening in your place (you can change the interval with the `-t` switch, see `man redshift`)

The [f.lux website](https://justgetflux.com/) describes pretty much the same thing:

> f.lux fixes this: it makes the color of your computer's display adapt to the time of day, warm at night and like sunlight during the day.

Comment: Right, but it just isn't working at all. There is no color temperature change, even after editing the configurations file to have a significant color temperature difference (2000s).

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Linux Mint 18.2, but it is based on Ubuntu 16.04 and I have many of the same problems pop up, including this one. I just managed to resolve this on my laptop running a GTX 940 on the Nvidia 384.90 Driver and I will test it on my desktop with a 1070 tomorrow.

As noted above I ran the following to list the Locations that redshift can use to base it's color:

`redshift -l list`

Then I ran

`redshift -l geoclue2`
which allowed me to start the redshift service and everything was working fine. I then moved on to making sure that it worked on startup by opening up 'Startup Applications' and adding the last command as a custom command there. By clicking 'run now' I was able to test that it still worked but also run it as a background service as opposed to directly in the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

I just `pause` the `f.lux` and then `un-pause` it, and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me changing the Adjustment Method in the settings menu from `drm` to `randr` made it work.